# How to start apache2 service , when it is in inactive state using ansible( When it is inactive state

Tags: ansible

Already apache2 is installed in my target node
I have to start apache2 service when it is in inactive state.
How to implement such kind of solution in ansible
I have to start apache2 service whenever it is inactive

Command: /sbin/service apache2 status
if the output is showing inactive then only i have to run below command

Command: /sbin/service apache2 start

Answer (score 0):

using adhoc ansible commands you should be able to run:

```
ansible <host_name_or_ip> -a "service httpd start"
```

or as part of a role:

```
- name: Ensure that apache2 is started
  become: true
  service: name=httpd state=started
```

Comment: Why not using the correct module with the ad-hoc command as well ?

Comment: Suppose apache2 is already in running state then the above command will work ?

Comment: @Zeitounator can you elaborate? Out of curiosity only, I don't use adhoc commands at all really so please correct me if my example is wrong :)

Comment: @MaheshReddy if httpd is already running then nothing will be changed, it will still just continue to run :)

Comment: @DSHolds Sure ! You can run the module from ad-hoc command like the following (rather than firing a command using shell...) `ansible [-i path/to/inventory] <name_or_ip> -m service -a "name=httpd state=started"`

Comment: @Zeitounator much cleaner, thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 0):

Ansible is about describing states in tasks that always produce the same result (idempotence). Your problem then comes down to:

- apache must be active on boot
- apache must be started

We could also add in a prior separate task:

- apache package must be installed on the system

A sample playbook would be

```
---
- name: Install and enable apache
  hosts: my_web_servers

  vars:
    package_name: apache2  # adapt to your distribution

  tasks:

    - name: Make sure apache is installed
      package:
        name: "{{ package_name }}"
        state: present

    - name: Make sure apache is active on boot and started
      service:
        name: "{{ package_name }}"
        enabled: true
        state: started
```

Running this playbook against your target host will (make sure you change the `hosts` param to a relevant group or machine):

- For the install task:

  - Install apache if it is not already installed and report "Changed"
  - Report "Ok" if apache is already installed
- For the service task:

  - Enable and/or start apache if needed and report "Changed"
  - Report "Ok" if apache is already enabled and started.

Note: in my example, I used the agnostic modules [`package`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/package_module.html) and [`service`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/service_module.html#service-module). If you which you can replace with their specific equivalent ([`apt`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/apt_module.html), [`yum`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_module.html) ... and [`systemd`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/systemd_module.html), [`sysvinit`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/sysvinit_module.html) ...)